# How should a composite variable be constructed?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of multiple variables which are used as the arguments of a function. I have collected all of the instances of the various values of the variables together with the output of the function corresponding to each instance of the values.

My goal is to collect in a 2D heatmap plot (i.e. a representation that can capture the values of three variables) the values of the output function, one of the arguments of the function and a composite variable that captures the character of the rest of the arguments of the function.

In Python, the function is of the following form:

```
def NN(epochs = None, hidden_nodes = None):
    # ... calculations...
    return score
```

The possible values of the variables can be listed in the following way:

```
epochs = [10, 100]
architecture = [
    [5, 10],
    [6, 11],
    [7, 12]
]
```

So, the various instances of the function being run look like the following:

```
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [5])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [10])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [5,   6])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [5,  11])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [10,  6])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [10, 11])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [5,   6,  7])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [5,   6, 12])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [5,  11, 12])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [10, 11, 12])
NN(epochs = 10, hidden_nodes = [5,  11,  7])
...

NN(epochs = 100, hidden_nodes = [ 5])
NN(epochs = 100, hidden_nodes = [10])
NN(epochs = 100, hidden_nodes = [5,   6])
...
```

I want to create a 2D "heatmap" plot (a plot with two axes and data points of colours that correspond to the value returned by the function). One of the axes is to correspond to the "epochs" variable and the other is to correspond to some composite variable that captures the unique character of each combination of the hidden nodes variables.

How could these values be combined into a composite variable such that it is of a unique value for each non-commutative combination of values while being some way comprehensible by humans (e.g. rationally transitioning from one group of variables to another)? It is important to note that the hidden nodes variables do not correspond to scores; they are just descriptors of an architecture.

Comment: If you know that your hidden_node values are in some fixed range (say $1$-$K$) for some number $K$, then you convert it to $H_1 + K*H_2 + K^2 * H_3 +...$. If $0$ is a possible value the hidden nodes, then you should add a constant value to them to prevent this first.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Hey, thanks for that. It can be a bit problematic if some values recur, but that works reasonably nicely as a way to differentiate the variables.